# Find duplicate site column using powershell script

Tags: powershell

When I try to add any content type it give error. I checked ULS and it say "no two choice should have same ID".
I checked google and find that I have to delete duplicate site column.
Can anyone please provide me powershell script which can provide me all duplicate site column which is created under website.

Comment: i have the same problème, you've found the script ?
Thanks

Comment: The problem is not that there is already duplicated columns, but that a column you are trying to create already exists. Update the GUIDS and StaticName, InternalName of the column that it says already exists (check in ULS logs which one it is).